# Updating SRC attribute of dynamically loaded image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dom, dynamically-generated

I am trying to dynamically load an image tag, and on the very next line, trying to change its SRC attribute. It is not working. Could it be because it does not allow enough 'time' for the image tag to load into a receptacle DIV (#Div_Extend_2), before its SRC attribute get changed? The whole image upload form is loaded dynamically, and if the image tag is included in the first dynamic inclusion, it works; I am able to change the SRC atribute of the image. But if the img tag is put there using load(), just before the change attribute statement: `$("#IMG_wlpst_PREV").attr('src',"IMAGES/Apples_in_a_basket.JPG");` is executed, it doesn't work.

Please note, in the CSS I have put `display: none;` for the image, when its included as part of the POST_IMG_1.PHP file.

Thank you, all help appreciated!! Please stay safe in this coronavirus period..
The main HTML document is as follows:

```
<div id='DIV_MAINPOST'>                 
        <div id="DV_post_type">                  
             <div id="div_POST_TXT">TEXT</div>     
             <div id="div_POST_IMG">Image!</div>             
        </div>              
        <div id="DIV_ERROR">    </div>
        <div id="Div_Extend_1"> </div>          
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
        
$('#DIV_MAINPOST').click(function(e){  
            switch(e.target.id) 
            { case "div_POST_TXT":
                    $('#Div_Extend_1').html("");
                    break;
              case "div_POST_IMG":
                    $('#Div_Extend_1').load('POST_IMAGE_1.php');                
                    break;
            }   });

        $('#DIV_MAINPOST').on('submit','#FORM_img', function(e){
            alert("formsubmit");
            e.preventDefault();
            var FD = new FormData(this);
            var FIL = FD.get("file_");          
            var ERS = 0;
            
            if(FIL.length===0)
            {   ERS++;  
                $("#DIV_ERROR").html("Error: No file");             
            }else if(!((FIL.type=='image/jpeg' ) || (FIL.type=='image/jpg') || (FIL.type=='image/png') || (FIL.type=='image/bmp')))
                {   ERS++;                              
                    $("#DIV_ERROR").html("Err: Not Image");                                         
                }else if(FIL.size > (6*1024*1024)) //> 4MB
                        {   ERS++;                                  
                            $("#DIV_ERROR").html("Err: Too Large");
                        }               
            if(ERS==0)
            {   $("#IMG_wlpst_PREV").show();      //case: 1  tag is present with POST_IMG_1.php, default css is display: none;
                $("#Div_Extend_2").load('POST_IMAGE_2.php');    // case: 2 loading tag with this stmt
                $("#IMG_wlpst_PREV").attr('src',"IMAGES/Apples_in_a_basket.JPG"); //updating its info                               
            }   });                         
});
```

POST_IMG_1.PHP

```
<FORM method='post' action='PHP/FILE_UPLOAD_CHECK.PHP' id="FORM_img" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <INPUT type='file' name='file_' size='10'></INPUT>
        <button type='submit' value='upload'>Upload</button>
    </FORM>                                                                             
    
    <div id="Div_Extend_2">
            <img id="IMG_wlpst_PREV"></img>   //case 1:: img tag included in the same file (which is also load()'ed, works fine. SRC gets updated.
                     //case 2:: this tag is not present, but the "Div_Extend_2" div is still present in POST_IMG_1.php.
    </div>
```

POST_IMG_2.PHP

```
<img id="IMG_wlpst_PREV"></img>     //case 2::if loaded using $("#Div_Extend_2").load('POST_IMG_2.PHP'), doesn't work;
```

CSS

```
#DIV_MAINPOST
{   width: 310px;   
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
#DV_post_type
{   order: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;  
}
#div_POST_TXT
{   order: 1;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: pink;
}
#div_POST_IMG
{   order: 2;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: pink; 
}
#DIV_ERROR
{   order: 2;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    color: red;
}
#Div_Extend_1                   
{    order: 3;
}                   
#IMG_wlpst_PREV
{   display: none; //case 1
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[image: Swati suggestion test]

Comment: Can you try like this `$('#Div_Extend_1').find("#IMG_wlpst_PREV").attr('src',"IMAGES/Apples_in_a_basket.JPG");` and see if that works .

Comment: Hi @Swati, just tried what you suggested. Still doesn't work; i have added a screenshot of the elements as appearing in the console and the whole thing, if you'd like to investigate more. Many appreciations!

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15254352/10606400) answer should work using callback inside `load` function.